# mapWithState().timeout() to trigger some function

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, session-timeout

I would like to use the `mapWithState().timeout()` function as an event to trigger some other function. Is there a way to do so?

I have read about some `statesnapshot()` to look for `timeout` log messages, but did not find enough intell about this. Would that the start for some kind of answer to my problem? And where to find more about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to use the `mapWithState().timeout()` function as an event
>   to trigger some other function. Is there a way to do so

Yes, it's possible. What you can do is define an action to be invoked once a timeout occurs. How do you know when a timeout has occured on a `MapWithStateRDD`? You can look at [`State[S].isTimingOut()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.streaming.State) method. This method will yield `true` once timeout has expired and `mapWithState` will execute the `StateSpec` method one last time with `value` being set to `None`:

```
object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spec = StateSpec.function(updateState _).timeout(Milliseconds(5))
    // Use spec to invoke `mapWithState`
  }

  def updateState(key: Int, value: Option[Int], state: State[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    value match {
      case Some(number) => Some(number + 1)
      case _ if state.isTimingOut() => // Trigger Code Here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering: Can I enforce the `timeout` of a `State`? I.e. Can I set the variable `isTimingOut()` is using to 1?

Comment: No. You can only set the timeout *period* when creating the `StateSpec`.